# Python import protocol buffer definitions from a different repository

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a repository which contains protocol buffer messages and services, originally written for a Golang project. I need to write a Python microservice but I'm not 100% clued up on how Python dependency management works. I need to import the definitions into my new Python project and compile them to Python.

How should I import my protocol buffer definitions repository into my Python project and compile the protobufs for Python? I can't copy the `.pb` files into my new project as they're shared amongst a number of other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Protobufs is installable via `pip`

```
$ pip install protobuf
```

Read [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) in the documentation if you need help on using pip.

Comment: Ok cool. How about importing my protobuf definitions from my local repository into my project? That's the thing that's really confusing me.

Comment: Have you read the [getting started](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial)? Also you may want to clarify your question then.

Comment: Hey Jonas, thanks for the link. I've clarified my question. I understand how to run `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto` but how do I import modules from a completely different repository and ensure everyone working on the project gets the latest versions?